# WebStorm ideaVim: prevent Ctrl-C go to visual block mode with

Tags: webstorm, ideavim

Press Ctrl+C will be in visual mode, how to prevent this.

```
# .ideavimrc
nnoremap <S-Left> :action EditorLeftWithSelection<CR>
nnoremap <S-Right> :action EditorRightWithSelection<CR>
nnoremap <S-Up> :action EditorUpWithSelection<CR>
nnoremap <S-Down> :action EditorDownWithSelection<CR>

inoremap <S-Left> <C-O>:action EditorLeftWithSelection<CR>
inoremap <S-Right> <C-O>:action EditorRightWithSelection<CR>
inoremap <S-Up> <C-O>:action EditorUpWithSelection<CR>
inoremap <S-Down> <C-O>:action EditorDownWithSelection<CR>
map <Home> g^ 
imap <Home> <c-o>g^
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have any mappings to `<C-C>` if you execute `:map` command?

Comment: No <C-c> in mappings.

Comment: What about your `~/.ideavimrc`?

Comment: The .ideavimrc file posted above.